# Delete directory contents with xquery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I want to essentially empty the contents of a directory ($directory) in MarkLogic without removing the directory itself. Using XQUERY I have tried the following:

```
let $_ := xdmp:directory-delete( $directory )
return xdmp:directory-create( $directory )
```

and as a sequence of operations:

```
(xdmp:directory-delete( $directory ), xdmp:directory-create( $directory ))
```

I get the error "Directory already exists".

I could try looping through each file in the directory and removing them, but that would leave the directories themselves. I want to totally wipe out all contents of the directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you must run each of these commands in different transactions using the xdmp:eval() function. Doing the following will work.

```
let $deleteCommand := "declare variable $directory as xs:string external; xdmp:directory-delete($directory)"
let $createCommand := "declare variable $directory as xs:string external; xdmp:directory-create($directory)"
let $_ := xdmp:eval($deleteCommand, (xs:QName("directory"), $directory),<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation><prevent-deadlocks>false</prevent-deadlocks></options>)
let $_ := xdmp:eval($createCommand, (xs:QName("directory"), $directory),<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>different-transaction</isolation><prevent-deadlocks>false</prevent-deadlocks></options>)
return $_
```

Running one of the commands in eval and calling the other does not work since this produces a deadlock.

Despite having this answer, I am still interested in a solution that deletes the contents of the directory if anyone has one.

Comment: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_24388 is well worth reading. It explains why you need two evals. You always want to run your updates in the first row of the "Calling Statement" table in that section. That is, when multiple updates are involved they should *always* be controlled by a read-only query. Calling updates from an update is at best impossible, and at worst dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply delete the directory and stop there. With MarkLogic you almost never need a directory to exist in the sense that `xdmp:directory-create` denotes.

See http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2012/03/19/directory-assistance/ for the longer story.